# Magento2 REST API and mode

Tags: rest-api, magento2.2.6

Magento2 has three different modes but official documents don't talk about how does Magento 2.2.6 REST APIs' behaves in these three different modes?

Comment: They should behave the same

Comment: Thanks. But what about performance , error reporting, exception logs? so it doesn't matter which mode I run in since I am only calling REST apis' ?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you are right. Magento doesn't include how the **Magento REST APIs** behave on the different modes or its behavior on each mode because **Magento REST APIs** are intended supposedly for integration or integrating your **Magento application** with **external or third party applications or systems** which means it doesn't really affect or be affected by the **internal modes** of the Magento.

Let's say you want to develop a **mobile app** of your Magento webshop, the Magento REST APIs provide you with the ability to manage your webshop, allowing requests for working with resources such as **customers, categories, products, and sales orders, and even carts and inventories** by providing or exposing **REST API endpoints** depending on the type of the user making the requests as discussed in the Magento REST API documentation.